# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable

Tags: php, sql

igot this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$arahan" in C:\xampp\htdocs\lenas_lovender\pesakit-kemaskini-proses.php on line 22

can someone pls check my coding

[image]

i think i alraedy declare the variable with the right way... but still i got this error

Comment: You've written &_POST instead of $_POST

Comment: please add semi colon on line 18 die statement

Answer (score -1):

Please try to maintain all your UPDATE query statement into one single line, it is giving an error because you are using new line without enabling word wrap of your code editor, so once you put all statement into one single line it will going to execute.